# How to add parameters to twimlResponse dial by nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

There is no information anywhere to add params to the twmil response throw  node.js.

I wanna add the tag param <param to the dial method in node.js but i couldn find informatio related to this.

Answer (score 0):

Using TwiML Bin Template Parameters
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/how-share-information-between-your-applications#using-twiml-bin-template-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To add a custom `<Parameter>` to a `<Client>` in Node.js you can use code like so:

```js
const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

const dial = twiml.dial({
  callerId: CALLER_ID
});
      
const client = dial.client();
client.identity("alice");
const parameter = client.parameter({
  name: "customerID", 
  value: "YOUR_CUSTOMER_ID"
});

console.log(twiml.toString());
// => <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
// <Response>
//   <Dial callerId="+1234557567">
//     <Client>
//       <Identity>alice</Identity>
//       <Parameter customerID="YOUR_CUSTOMERID"/>
//     </Client>
//   </Dial>
// </Response>
```

Note, that you can't add parameters directly to the `<Dial>` element, just the `<Client>` element within it. If you need to pass information on after the `<Dial>` completes, then you should add URL parameters to the URL you provide as the [`action` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#action).

Let me know how you get on with that.